# how to make record status No when we insert same record again

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have list files downloading and moving data to database multiple times.If i insert same data to database second time, i have to make column name recordstatus to 'N' which has two values 'Y' and 'N'. I am not getting a proper logic in order to implent,any put some thoughts here

Comment: Before inserting the data you need to query if the similar record do exist, if so then you can insert it with recordstatus N

Comment: Thanks done:) same logic used